# pass function parameter to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have two functions `function A(str)` and `function B(id)`:

```
function A(str) {

}

function B(id) {
  $x = str
}
```

Is there a way to pass the parameter `str` in `function A` to `function B`?

Comment: How are you invoking `A`/`B` function?

Comment: Simple call the b function inside a

Comment: That will not work, @AyazShah. `str` is not within the lexical scope of `B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either assign to a variable in scope of both A and B

```
let outerStr;
function A(str) {
  outerStr = str;
}

function B(id) {
  const $x = outerStr;
}
```

Or call B with arguments with the `str`:

```
function A(str) {
  B(null, str);
}

function B(id, strParam) {
  const $x = strParam;
}
```

(or use `this` or `arguments` - not recommended, but doable)

Answer (score 0):

You can store your variable outside of your functions to make it available to both and change it in `A()`

```js
var strA;

function A(str) {
  strA = str;
}

function B(id) {
  var x = strA;
  console.log(x);
}

A("Lorem");
B("anID");
```